# Preg_replace не заменяет

Tags: php

Что не так в этом коде, он не заменяет нужное значение на пустоту

```
echo preg_replace("/<events>(.*?)<\/events>/","/ /",$list);
```

Comment: этот запрос по идее заменяет всю найденую строку

Comment: Добавьте **s** модификатор, видимо есть переводы строк в целевом тексте. В остальном выражение верное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот работающий вариант:

```
echo preg_replace("#(?<=<events>).*?(?=</events>)#is","  ",$list);
```

http://ideone.com/Liw3KP

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/k9FzDOl9Sw8USga0)

Comment: Увы, не работает.

Comment: как это не работает если я даже пример вам сделал ?

Comment: Вот текст из которого достаю. Получаю его через file_get_contents http://pastebin.com/np23rz3W

Comment: нужен модификатор s, поправил ответ.